# SSIS via Import Wizard SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have a flat file i need to import into SQL. For a lot of boring reasons, I curently don't have access to use BIDS, only the import wizard in SSMS. The flat file looks sort of like:

```
A    
2    
B    
G    
-blank line here-    
8    
R    
F    
6
```

Basically, a few lines, separated by an empty line, Repeat a few thousand times. The text field here doesn't show it all that well, if you have questions about that, I can try to clarify.

What i need is for each of those groups to be its own row, merged together with a delimiter. So, the data in the table would look like:

```
A,2,B,G
8,R,F,6
```

Only one column in the table, with a delimited string of data in that column.

Can this be accomplished via the wizard? If not, can it be accomplished with BIDS and a real SSIS package? That may be an option, but it will probably be a while before I have access to that, and by that time, it may be moot.

Comment: What about PowerShell, not thinking about it much but if I could not get access to SSIS think that would be my next path to check. Only other thing might be T-SQL query using bulk insert maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the wizard and load the data into a temp table then process it from there.  That's probably your easiest option.  Unfortunately while I know there is a relatively easy way to do the processing I just can't remember what it is.

The other option is going to be to use BIDS and you will probably have to use a script source to construct your input.

Answer (score 0):

I would possibly run a short program that picks up the original text file and basically just runs a string replace. If the blank line is genuinely blank then search for newline (\n\r) and convert to , then search for ,, and convert to newline and then dump the result out to a new text file - or something similar.

Probably need tweaking and as I don't know the format of the file the above might not be practical, but basically convert the file to the format you want before importing?